# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting location details from database as a json response and values are coming correctly but my problem is the alignment of content string getting error like unterminated string literal ...

then i am displaying this details in google map info window..

```
 var contentString = "<div><h4>Start Location : "+ locations[i].start_loc + "</h4>
                           <h4> Driver Name : "+ locations[i].driver_name + "</h4>
                           <h4> Driver Mob No : "+ locations[i].mob_num + "</h4>
                           <h4> Passenger Name : "+locations[i].passenger_name + "</h4>
                           <h4> Passenger Mob No : "+locations[i].mob_no + "</h4>
                           <h4> Cab Reg No : "+ locations[i].cab_reg_no + "</h4></div>"; 

                    infowindow.setContent(start_contentString);
                    infowindow.open(start_map, start_marker);
```

Please help me anyone....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\` after every line:

```
var contentString = "<div><h4>Start Location : "+ test + "</h4> \
                           <h4> Driver Name : "+ locations[i].driver_name + "</h4> \
                           <h4> Driver Mob No : "+ locations[i].mob_num + "</h4> \
                           <h4> Passenger Name : "+locations[i].passenger_name + "</h4> \
                           <h4> Passenger Mob No : "+locations[i].mob_no + "</h4> \
                           <h4> Cab Reg No : "+ locations[i].cab_reg_no + "</h4></div>";
```

Comment: Thank You it's working now ...why escape ( \ ) added?? can you please explain

Comment: @mathi - it's used to escape the literal new line character. You could instead write every line like my answer below, added for reference only

Answer (score 0):

Answer just to show alternative multiline...

```
var contentString = "<div><h4>Start Location : "+ test + "</h4>" + 
                       "<h4> Driver Name : "+ locations[i].driver_name + "</h4>" +
                       "<h4> Driver Mob No : "+ locations[i].mob_num + "</h4>" +
                       "<h4> Passenger Name : "+locations[i].passenger_name + "</h4>" +
                       "<h4> Passenger Mob No : "+locations[i].mob_no + "</h4>" +
                       "<h4> Cab Reg No : "+ locations[i].cab_reg_no + "</h4></div>";
```